# Is this a valid proof of surjectivity?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Problem: Determine whether the function $f: [3, \infty) \to [5,\infty)$ given by $f(x) = (x-3)^2+5$ is surjective.

Answer.  It is surjective.
Proof:
Let $\omega \in [5,\infty)$.  I claim that $z=\sqrt{\omega-5}+3$ maps to $\omega$ for some $z \in [3,\infty)$.

So $f(z) = (z-3)^2+5 = ((\sqrt{\omega-5}+3)-3)^2+5 = \omega$ as intended. $\square$

Does the proof end here?  It seems like I should verify that $z$ is always in the domain or something.

Comment: You're done: $z\in[3,\infty)$ because $\sqrt{w-5}$ (which is well-defined for $w\geq 5$) is nonnegative.

Comment: The wording is slightly faulty: as you have given a specific expression for $z$, you should not be saying "for some $z\in[3,\infty)$".  And yes, you should check that $z$ is in the domain, but I think you will find this is very easy.

Comment: You are effectively done, but you should state at the end why $x\in[3,\infty)$, as Kim points out.

Comment: @David If I don't assume that $z \in [3, \infty)$ how do I prove that it is?  Do I need to show that $f(3)=5$ and that the function increases without bound & is continuous?

Comment: To show that $z\in[3,\infty)$, you need only show that no matter what $\omega$ is, $\sqrt{\omega-5}+3 \ge 3$. Now use Kim's comment.